# Бесконечная анимация движения canvas

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas

Нужно, чтобы астероид пролетал за границы экрана и потом снова вылетал с другой стороны. И так по-кругу. Помогите, пожалуйста
(Я новичок и делаю чисто в обучающих целях, не судите код строго :) )

**HTML:**

```
<h2>14) Анимация Canvas</h2>
```

**JS:**

```
    window.onload = () => {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas2');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Background
    let backgroundImg = new Image();
    backgroundImg.src = 'https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/640x480/2/bf/kosmos-zvezdy-planeta-5363.jpg';

    // Main objects
    let asteroid = new Image();
    asteroid.src = 'img/asteroid.png';

    let asteroid2 = new Image();
    asteroid2.src = 'img/asteroid.png';

    let x = 0;
    let y = getRandomNum(0, 400);

    backgroundImg.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(asteroid, x, y, 75, 75);
    }

    draw();

    function draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        ctx.drawImage(asteroid, x, y, 75, 75);

        let inter = setInterval(moveAsteroid, 5);

        function moveAsteroid() {
            if(x == 715) {
                clearInterval(moveAsteroid);
            }
            else {
                ctx.clearRect(0,0, 640, 480);
                ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                ctx.drawImage(asteroid, x, y, 75, 75);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getRandomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: HTML ещё: <canvas id="canvas2" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

Comment: А в чём вопрос то?

Comment: Чтобы астероид вылетал за границы canvas и вылетал с другой стороны

Comment: >Чтобы астероид вылетал за границы canvas и вылетал с другой стороны< Это не вопрос :) Вас интересует, "как сделать так, чтобы астероид при улетании за пределы экрана вылетал с другой стороны в том же месте?", так?

Comment: Да) я позиционировал это, как вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам будет достаточно следующего:

```
function moveAsteroid() {
    if(x == 715) {
        clearInterval(moveAsteroid);
    }
    else {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, 640, 480);
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        ctx.drawImage(asteroid, x, y, 75, 75);
        x++;
    }
    if (x >= width)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Кусок

```
if (x >= width)
{
    x = 0;
}
```

переместит ваш астероид на другую сторону экрана, как только он улетит слишком далеко вправо.

Comment: Точно, спасибо :)